# Intermittent connectivity when browsing to server / 2008 X64

Tags: windows-server-2008

This is happening on two different servers. One hosts Exchange 2007 and the other OWA. When I try to browse to `\\server\c$` it will sit there for a long time and then either time out or the contents will display. There is not pattern to how it acts. Other times it will browse right to the folder with no issues.

Servers: Windows Server 2008 Standard x64
I never lose packets while pinging the server it just happens when trying to browse to the server shares.

Has anyone else experienced this problem?

Comment: Does the same problem occur with any firewall disabled?

Comment: Is this problem impacting any services being offered by the servers?

Comment: I am trying to Virtualize the server using VMM. It will not install the agent because it cant see the share. Besides that it is not impacting any services.

Comment: It still does this with the firewall disabled.

Comment: Have you tried connecting by using the ip address in the UNC path? If so, and if that works consitently, then I'd say you have a name resolution problem.

Comment: I tried that as well, it does the exact same thing with the host name or the IP.